# Best way to handle the re-rendering in reusable components

Tags: reactjs, components

I would like to create my own reusable components that can be used in other projects (**as npm package**).

Let assume that the reusable components are structured in this way:

```
ui
├───card.jsx
├───card-board.jsx
├───card-body.jsx
├───sliding.jsx
├───sliding-board.jsx
├───sliding-body.jsx
├───img.jsx
├───remove.jsx
├───title.jsx
└───index.jsx
```

Usage Example:

```
this.state.Cards.map(card => {
  return (
    <Card key={card.id}>
      <Remove onRemove={() => this.handleCardRemove(card.id)} />
      <Img />
      <CardBody>
        <Title>{card.title}</Title>
        <p>{card.body}</p>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
});
```

It worked great until the number of cards are **overpopulated**. All the update and delete function became really slow due to the waste re-rendering on the same static content.

And of course this can be optimized by checking the previous and the new props on the **Card component** as below:

```
import React from "react";

import { CardContainer } from "./card.style";
import { deepCompare } from "../../utils/";

const Card = ({ children }) => {
  return <CardContainer>{children}</CardContainer>;
};

// if return true - Card component won't re-render
const arePropsEqual = (preProps, newProps) => {
  return deepCompare(preProps, newProps); // <- function that compare the nested props.
};

export default React.memo(Card, arePropsEqual);
```

As you can see. I'm using **React.memo** to control the re-rendering and I also implemented the **deepCompare function** that will return true if both input props are the same.

So, I would like to know what is the best way to handle this kind of problem in the large scale where there are a lot of components (probably nested).

And, Should the above solution(React.memo) be applied for each **individual** ui component that I created?. Because some of the ui element can be used individually without depending on some kind of container eg: Img, Remove and Title component.

Comment: How many cards are rendered when you experience the problem?

Comment: @Kunukn Well, the lag start to appear when there are more than 1,000 cards.

Comment: If the idea is that you want to have 1000+ cards available, but maybe not all visible at the same time. Then I suggest to looking to libraries like `React window` https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

Comment: @Kunukn Thank for your suggestion. Actually, I have heard the idea "render only element that visible". However, the main objective that I want is that I would like to create the reusable components that can handle the re-rendering automatically. So the user don't have to write the extra code for detecting the changes of the content in the particular component.

Comment: I suspect what you want is not feasible with React. I can't come up with a solution. 

If you want to render 1000+ components and be able to handle re-rendering fast, then maybe React is not the right tool.

React's approach is to use a reconciler and iterative visit all child nodes, and ask them to render them-self